# How to set repetition when timeout exception occurs

Tags: java

I've used JAXWS-RI 2.1 to create an interface for my web service, based on a WSDL. I can interact with the web service no problems, but haven't been able to specify repetition when SocketTimeoutException:

```
try {
  final Response response = service.serviceName(params);
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {

}
```

is there a way how to specify it in service or I need to code this ?

for example I would set for 3 repetation and when after 3 exception there will be stil timemout so this exception will be thrown

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native way to do this (I suspect you're coming from Ruby, where this is a language feature). You will need to loop, then break on success e.g.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
    try {
        final Response response = service.serviceName(params);
        break;
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Thread.getCurrentThread().sleep(10 * 1000);
    }
}
```